# How can I make jquery script shorter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I have got following code (i shorted it to make it more readable)
And I would like to ask if it is possible to do not write almost the same code for every button? How can I do it the easiest way? I have got 6 buttons and code would be quite long.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#option1").click(function(){
            if($(".option1").is(":visible")){
                $(".option1").hide("slow",function(){});
            }
            else{
                $(".option2, .option3").hide("slow",function(){});
                $(".option1").show("slow",function(){});
            }
        });
        $("#option2").click(function(){
            if($(".option2").is(":visible")){
                $(".option2").hide("slow",function(){});
            }
            else{
                $(".option1, .option3").hide("slow",function(){});
                $(".option2").show("slow",function(){});
            }
        });
        $("#option3").click(function(){
            if($(".option3").is(":visible")){
                $(".option3").hide("slow",function(){});
            }
            else{
                $(".option1, .option2").hide("slow",function(){});
                $(".option3").show("slow",function(){});
            }
         });
    });
</script>
<body>
    <div class="containter">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button type="button" id="option1" class="btn btn-primary">Button1 >></button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button type="button" id="option2" class="btn btn-primary">Button2 >></button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button type="button" id="option3" class="btn btn-primary">Button3 >></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you have a JSfiddle?

Comment: I would say put your if/else statements in a function and pass in the class names.

Comment: As a side note:  Your current code is looking for classes but you don't have those classes defined in the html.  They're id's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the code to just one click listener. Try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn-primary").click(function() {
        var option = $(this).data("option");
        if ($(".option." + option).is(":visible")) {
            $(".option." + option).hide("slow", function() {});
        } else {
            $(".option").not("." + option).hide("slow", function() {});
            $(".option." + option).show("slow", function() {});
        }
    });
});
</script>
<body>
    <div class="containter">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button type="button" id="option1" data-option="option1" class="btn btn-primary">Button1 >></button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button type="button" id="option2" data-option="option2" class="btn btn-primary">Button2 >></button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button type="button" id="option3" data-option="option3" class="btn btn-primary">Button3 >></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- common class option added -->
    <div class="options">
        <div class="option option1"></div>
        <div class="option option2"></div>
        <div class="option option3"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I added a common class to all the options, and a data-option attribute to your buttons.

Answer (score 2):

Without the need to change much of your html, add a common class `option` to all your option1, option2, ... :

```
<div class ="option option1">a</div>
<div class ="option option2">b</div>
<div class ="option option3">c</div>
```

and then you can use this below:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('button')).forEach(function(btn){
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        if($("." + e.target.id).is(":visible")){
                $("." + e.target.id).hide("slow",function(){});
            }
        else{
                $(".option").hide("slow",function(){});
                $("." + e.target.id).show("slow",function(){});
            }
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ggd6t9s8/)

Comment: This looks great, just out of curiosity, why mix jQuery and native JS instead of doing it all in one or the other?

Comment: I would have done it in pure javascript for myself, but I wanted to use `hide`and `show` for the OP to see. @mituw16, though you're totally right, one or the other would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check to see whether the current button is visible.  It's visible because it was just clicked on.

All you need to do is show the other buttons that weren't clicked on and hide the one that was.  To do this, assign the same class to all 3 buttons.  In the example below, I added the class "myBtn" to all 3 buttons.

```
$(".myBtn").click(function () {
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   $(".myBtn:not(#"+id+")").show("slow", function () {});
   $(this).hide();
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fm136gpj/2/) demo.